# Executing Child Component Function from Parent Component

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I'm facing an issue with executing a function from a child component when triggered by an event in the parent component. Here's a breakdown of my situation:

I have a React application with two components: ParentComponent and ChildComponent. In ChildComponent, there's a function handleFocusInput that's responsible for focusing on an input field. In ParentComponent, I have a function handleClickJumpToError that should execute handleFocusInput when it's triggered.

**Code:**

**ChildComponent:**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const ChildComponent = ({ onJumpToError }) => {
const newPasswordRef = useRef(null);

const handleFocusInput = () => {
  if (newPasswordRef.current) {
  newPasswordRef.current.focus();
}
};

return (
<div>
  <input ref={newPasswordRef} type="text" />
  <button onClick={() => { handleFocusInput(); onJumpToError(); }}>Focus Input and 
    Jump</button>
</div>
 );
 };

 export default ChildComponent;
```

**ParentComponent:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const ParentComponent = () => {
 const handleClickJumpToError = () => {
    console.log("Jumping to error");
  // Perform any actions related to jumping to error
  };




 return (
   <div>
    <ChildComponent onJumpToError={handleClickJumpToError} />
  </div>
  );
 };

  export default ParentComponent;
```

**Desired Outcome:**

I want to trigger the handleFocusInput function from ChildComponent whenever the handleClickJumpToError function is executed in ParentComponent. Currently, when the button in ChildComponent is clicked, the input is focused, but I also want to perform the actions from handleClickJumpToError.

**Question:**

How can I ensure that the handleFocusInput function is executed in ChildComponent when the handleClickJumpToError function is triggered in ParentComponent? Is there a better way to handle this interaction between parent and child components?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in children component delete handleFocusInput function:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export const ChildComponent = ({ onJumpToError }) => {
  const newPasswordRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={newPasswordRef} type="text" />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          onJumpToError(newPasswordRef.current);
        }}
      >
        Focus Input and Jump
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and parent component add item focus in function:

```
  const handleClickJumpToError = (item) => {
    console.log("Jumping to error");
    if(item)  item.focus();
    // Perform any actions related to jumping to error
  };
```